# HTML5 javascript framework for datagrid (or spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid, frameworks

I have been doing some digging around on the Internet and I’m wondering if you know of a product.

I’m looking for a robust HTML5 javascript framework for datagrid (or spreadsheet) where it can do those following when displaying on webpage…

1) Having data, textboxes, drop-down selection, checkboxes, etc. (in columns) per rows...

2) Be able to group several columns (of data) and display rows like this…
(Say you group the Make, Model and Color…)

```
(-) Ford (5)
   (-) Mustang (3)
      (+) Green (1)
      (-) Blue (2)
         (Year) (Trim) (Mileage) (Color)
         2007 2dr Coupe 52,000 Green
         2012 2dr Sedan 23,321 Blue
   (+) Ranger (3)
   (+) Taurus (5)

(+) Chevrolet (8)

(-) Toyota (2)
   (-) Prius (2)
      (-) Yellow (2)
         (Year) (Trim) (Mileage) (Color)
         2013 3dr Hatchback 14,021 Yellow
         2010 2dr Coupe 11,123 Yellow
```

Thanks…

Comment: Sadly to say but I think your best shot would be with `ExtJS4.x`

Comment: I have seen examples there but no multiple columns grouping like this or html form elements in those cells.  I can try posting a question at the forum to see if that help

Comment: Personally I don't like ExtJS it has very high learning curve in my opinion, but it's powerful. I've been working with it for about 6months and actually it's pretty suited for what you need. Even if there's no exact example by using ExtJS you can get what you need. And if you use it frequently enough it may even worth the time spending to learn it. And just to mention, it may be very questionable what is and what isn't framework, but there are not so much JS/HTML frameworks. You gonna find mostly libraries like `jQuery`.

Comment: Yes, ExtJS does have high learning curve.  I tried building one a year ago and took me 2 weeks, nowhere to getting it done and not able to get it to do what I need it to do.<br><br>One thing that bother me about JQuery is that it kept getting broken when you bump to newer version or is nowhere close to it.

Comment: That's why I said `sadly`. ExtJS is far from perfect but still it's one of the most powerful frameworks on the market. When I was using ExtJS on regular basis I saw this chart where `jQuery` was shown as the most used at all, but ExtJS was the number one choice for big projects. So as I see the things this is the deal - either you do something little and you just need a solution - then don't bother learning ExtJS-like F/w, but if you gonna do something complex then better spend some time learning than seeking for hacks and inventing the wheel over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try googling for **jquery datagrid plugin**, and you will probably find one.
However for full control over your grid, consider making your own soultion 
using **backbone & underscore stack** ([here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)). You will have ultimate control over your data & presentation and it is a pretty **lightweight & flexible**  solution compared to EXT.js

Comment: I'm not too familiar w/ backbone.  I decided to go w/ JQuery jqGrid but it doesn't support this feature I'm looking for but I am pleased to see the the source code is continously updating weekly/monthly.  So, for now I'm gonna write custom jquery script to add this feature as a workaround.  See link http://jsfiddle.net/tpeczek/vRtKS/

Comment: In the meantime, I got hold of angular.js. Learn that. It will radically reduce your pain once you get the hang of it.